# Can I make a dynamic .htaccess file?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

Can I make my .htaccess be generated with php?
I would like to use php to dynamicly create my htaccess file from information from the database.
It would save me the trouble of making a new .htaccess file whenever I change a bit of my code.

Comment: They don't call you Insanity for nuthin. There are better ways of accomplishing what you want.

Comment: if it were possible, you would need access to the httpd.conf/Apache config. The problem is that you would need an .htaccess file to add the .htaccess file as an executable. Even then, I'm pretty sure Apache would still see this file as a text file, so it wouldn't execute the PHP upon reading it. It sounds like a really cool and interesting thing to play around with, but like Byron said, there's better ways to accomplish whatever benefits you could get out of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read and write files with the [file system functions](http://php.net/ref.filesystem), for example:

```
$data = <<<EOF
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule …
EOF;
file_put_contents('.htaccess', $data);
```

But it would be more flexible if you use one static rule that redirect the requests to your PHP file that then does the rest.

Comment: Hm, i have a bunch of rewrites, that rewrite to my index.php with diffrent get vars

Comment: Are you sure you can't handle this rewrite with one general rule, then check for a valid get variable (which you need to do anyway for security) within index.php?

Comment: This answer actully makes most sense, as I can make a cron job to gen the .htaccess

Comment: @InsanityNet: I was rather thinking of a PHP variant of this routing. When using a uniform, hierarchical URL design, you can easily pass the request to the corresponding scripts.

Comment: Yes, but I also like using clean urls.

Comment: @InsanityNet: They are not mutually exclusive. In fact, the application (PHP) does know what the URLs mean better than your web server (.htaccess). So it should be the application that does the request parsing and not the web server. That would also eliminate writing rewrite rules dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Can you?  Sure.  You can create files in the filesystem with PHP so long as you have permissions.

Should you?  Well, if you are only using PHP in "command-line" mode, I suppose it's as good as another scripting language.  If you are doing so from a website, I would say this is a bad idea for security reasons.  Another technology might be more appropriate (if you originally had XML, then XSLT would come to mind, but you're using mysql, so you'll need some other kind of script).

Comment: How does this help my question? You wouldn't use .htaccess in command line mode.....

Comment: No, but that isn't stopping you from generating it, just as you might with some other script.  If you're wanting to generate it *from a web page call*, that's a different matter.

Comment: No, I would like to basicly tell apache to call .htaccess (like it does), parse it in php, _then_ parse it in apache

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can generate your .htaccess with PHP if you had a backend script to do it - say in your admin area. But it seems risky and potentially unnecessary? if something goes wrong, your site will be down until you fix it - that potentially means the page you're using to generate it. Why not just create an interface that generates the new rules for you from a database, then you can have a quick look over and copy them in?

What exactly is it that you're trying to update?