# Dynamic .htaccess file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

As part of a project, we're currently looking at adding in SEO URLs to pages. This is for an online store, and there are numerous types of content within the site: static pages (for example "About Us", "Privacy Policy", product categories and product pages.

We have the numerous URL stubs stored in a MySQL table as follows:

```
+-----------------+------------------+----------------+
|    url_stub     | destination type | destination_id |
+-----------------+------------------+----------------+
| privacy-policy/ |       page       |       1        |
+-----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   category-1/   |     category     |       2        |
+-----------------+------------------+----------------+
|  my-product-1/  |      product     |       1        |
+-----------------+------------------+----------------+
```

One option to serve these up would be to have a huge index.php file which is capable of handling everything, however, we would much prefer to have separate pages to serve up the different content types. For example anything with a `destination_type` of `page` would go to page.php?id=#, and so forth. So, for the examples in the table above, these would be directed as follows:

```
privacy-policy/ = page.php?id=1
category-1/     = category.php?cat=2
my-product-1/   = product.php?prod=1
```

My question is this: what would be the best practice to achieve this? We don't want to include the `destination_id` anywhere in the SEO-friendly URL. I was thinking that it might be possible to create a dynamic .htaccess file which outputs everything on the fly with `mod_rewrite`, but I can't find any solutions.

Any help or comments would be most gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer would be "no you have to rewrite it every time" but this older question should answer yours :) [Can I make a dynamic .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816209/can-i-make-a-dynamic-htaccess-file)

Otherwise, complicated/stupid/useless idea:

```
RewriteRule /(.*)  /index.php?url=$1
```

Then in your PHP file

```
if (isset($_GET['url']))
{
  //Parse url and echo page according to requested url
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. So, are there any solutions at all?

Comment: Edited to give you the most dynamic rewrite you can have if you want to use a database for your rewrites.