# Edit .htacces. file on page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I wonder if it is possible to create a function on page to write rules in the .htaccess file. What I'm trying to do exactly is creating a page on my admin panel for changing page URL's.

Example:
http://example.com/page.php?id=1 to http://example.com/home

I know this is possible with the RewriteRule in the .htaccess file, but I wan't to do this with for example a form selection (for selecting the page that needs URL changing) and a inpufield for the value that needs to be showed instead of the original filename.

I've been searching for a while, but haven't found a solution or clarifying answer. I need to know if this is possible or not and where to find some information about this.

Hope someone here can help me out.

Simple example of what I'm trying to create:

[image]

Comment: Sure, this is possible, but it's probably not a good idea. You should not dynamically rewrite your web server configuration. If you need something like configurable routing, you should create one static .htaccess rule which forwards all requests to a specific PHP file, which then handles the routing based on database data, or some such.

Comment: .htaccess is a file. with PHP you can open (read & write) files. So when the users submit the form - use PHP to open the .htaccess file and update its content with the new rewrite rule. Just keep in mind that it's up to you to make sure it's valid.

Comment: @deceze Thankyou for your answer. This is new to me, can you tell me where to find some information about creating such static .htaccess rule? When I search for information I only find how to change the URL inside the file.

Comment: @Kussensloop deceze describes the front controller pattern, where all requests are routed to the same PHP file (so only one rule is needed in .htaccess). See https://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/ for example

Comment: I found this, that looks like what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3816235/8695939 But, like @deceze and many others said, it might be a bad idea : pay attention to security issues. <br>
I hope I helped a bit :)